# How to reference more than one element in an handlebars helper block on node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, handlebars.js, node-modules

So, I have an object like this:

```
object = {
 "group_1": [
  {
   "name": "Foo"
  }
 ],
 "group_2": [
  {
   "name": "Bar"
  }
 ]
}
```

And in my hbs view I'm doing like this:

```
{{#each group_1}}
 <p>{{name}}</p>
{{/each}}

{{#each group_2}}
 <p>{{name}}</p>
{{/each}}
```

Is there any way of concatenating both and not repeating code? The solution would be something like this:

```
{{#each group_1 + group_2}}
 <p>{{name}}</p>
{{/each}}
```

Any idea how to do this?

Comment: You can't do it in handlebars. 

Another option would be to concatenate the arrays in JavaScript and then use the concatenated array instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Handlebars itself does not support this.
But you can still do:

```js
object.groups = object.group_1.concat(object.group_2);
```

```html
{{#each groups}}
<p>{{name}}</p>
{{/each}}
```

Which seems to be a straightforward solution.

Alternatively you can put both your groups into an object and iterate over it like this:

```js
let object = {
 groups: {
  'group_1': [
   {
    'name': 'Foo'
   }
  ],
  'group_2': [
   {
    'name': 'Bar'
   }
  ]
 }
};
```

```html
{{#each groups}}
    {{!-- you can refference group name as @key here --}}
 {{#each this}}
  {{name}}
 {{/each}}
{{/each}}
```